# Create shortcut for electrum bitcoin wallet

Tags: python, python3

I installed Electrum bitcoin wallet from electrum.org but don't know how to launch it or create a shortcut for it.

These are the commands I used:

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pyqt5 python3-pip
```

Install Electrum:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install https://download.electrum.org/3.3.3/Electrum-3.3.3.tar.gz#egg=electrum[fast]
```

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)!, the link that you gave are tar.gz file, you can download it, extract it and install it using `python3 setup.py install`...

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have a file called `electrum` in `.local/bin/`

If present, run this Terminal command :

```
~/.local/bin/electrum
```